# If $AB$ is diagonally dominant, is $ADB$ diagonally dominant for positive diagonal $D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-square real matrices such that $AB$ is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).
Let $D$ be a positive diagonal real matrix.

Is $ADB$ diagonally dominant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another counterexample, with smaller numbers . . .

Let $A,D,B$ be given by
$$
A =
\pmatrix
{
1 & 1 & 1 \cr
1 & 1 & 2
}
,\;\;
D =
\pmatrix
{
1 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 1 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 2
}
,\;\;
B =
\pmatrix
{
2 & 1 \cr
3 & 1 \cr
1 & 3
}
$$
Then we have
$$AB = 
\pmatrix
{
6 & 5 \cr
7 & 8
}
\\[20pt]
ADB = 
\pmatrix
{
7 & 8 \cr
9 & 14
}
$$
so $AB$ is diagonally dominant, but $ADB$ is not diagonally dominant.

Comment: Thank you! After asking the question I realized I could at least search for counter examples with python, and my answer was the first counter example that was randomly found.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & 7\\
 3 & 8 & 5 \end{bmatrix}\\
B = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 4\\
5 & 9\\
8 & 5 \end{bmatrix}\\
D = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 8 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\\
$$

Then:
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix} 78 & 65\\
 92 & 109 \end{bmatrix}\\
ADB = \begin{bmatrix} 228 & 250\\
436 & 662 \end{bmatrix}\\
$$